# RadGrid change column header not working

Tags: radgrid, prerender

I am trying to change the column header. When I do so it does not show the radgrid at all. If I comment the code inside of rdMain_PreRender the grid show up fine.  Am I doing something wrong.

```
    <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="rdMain" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Skin="Metro" OnPreRender="rdMain_PreRender" DataSourceID="MainSource" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true">
                        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" CommandItemDisplay="None">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" ReadOnly="true" />
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />                                    


                                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                                    ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" />
                            </Columns>
                            <EditFormSettings>
                                <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                            </EditFormSettings>
                        </MasterTableView>
                        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                    </telerik:RadGrid>





        protected void rdMain_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var masterTableView = rdMain.MasterTableView;
            var column = masterTableView.GetColumn("Phone");
            column.HeaderText = "TelePhone";
            masterTableView.Rebind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the unique name of the columns in the grid and try using the next line of code in PreRender:

```
rdMain.Columns.FindByUniqueName("Phone").HeaderText = "TelePhone";
```

Hope it works.